# Write a nodejs program that prints “Hello World!” as the output for all the routes of the application

Tags: node.js

Write a nodejs program that prints “Hello World!” 
as 
the output for all the routes of the application

i am getting some logical error

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps

```
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello')
})
```

Comment: var express = require('express');
var app = express();


app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
res.send('hello world')
});



app.listen(3000, function() {
 console.log('Live at Port 3000');
});

Comment: still i am getting logical error , i don't understand where i am doing wrong